# How do you distinguish between the terms "perfect gas" and "ideal gas"?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, definition, ideal-gas

I know that [Ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas) vs [Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_gas) gas has been discussed somewhere already but obviously it is a pointless discussion and the reason is as follows. If you define Ideal Gas and also if you define Perfect Gas and your definitions are indistinguishable then Ideal Gas=Perfect Gas. If you define them both and the definitions are not the same then Perfect Gas≠Ideal Gas. Definitions reflect some particular need/application and are not carved in stone therefore different authors will come up with their own definitions depending on perceived needs.

The most basic definition of the Ideal Gas seems to be that a system consists of particles that may or may not mutually interact (have potentials) but for the sake of the model those interactions can be thought as negligible. Colloquially one can say there are no inderactions but I don't like such oversimplifications. The Ideal Gas equation can be derived from this.

So my question is, wouldn't be correct to say that the most common definition for the Perfect Gas is that it is a gas that has certain specific properties. An Ideal Gas would be an example for a Perfect Gas; but so would be Van der Waals gas because it is perfect in the sense that statistically it's properties obey specific rules.

Real gases are not Perfect because they're more complicated; they don't follow statistical distributions because every particle would have to be considered separately; plus we don't know all the laws of physics therefore no Perfect Gas model would apply to real gases.

Would you consider it a viable way of differentiating between Ideal and Perfect Gas? The former being clearly defined but refinements can be made which may lead to a concept of a Perfect Gas?

Answer (score 1):

A perfect gas is an overarching category of models of a gas that contains all of the gas models that disregard inter-particle interactions, including the ideal gas model. See [this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_gas) for more detail.

An "ideal gas" is a *type of* perfect gas; i.e. all ideal gases are perfect gases, but not all perfect gases are ideal gases. While an ideal gas must be a perfect gas because inter-particle interactions are disregarded in the model, *it is not necessarily the case that a perfect gas must be an ideal gas* as for a model to be an ideal gas, it must follow the ideal gas law, $PV = nRT$.

To use an analogy, consider an "ideal gas" a species, and a "perfect gas" its genus/family/what have you.

Comment: This answer does not agree with the wiki article you linked to. You say that difference is a perfect gas need not obey the ideal gas law, however the wiki page claims that, whilst both obey the ideal gas law, a perfect gas has constant heat capacity (as a function of temperature) but an ideal gas does not. I don't want to way in too heavily on which is correct, as I have never encountered a case where (I noticed) the terms were being used differently, but for what its worth I am pretty sure the ideal gas law follows almost immediately from neglecting iterations, with very few extra assumptions

Comment: That is fair enough; it seems to me as if the actual terms themselves are not clearly defined, their use relying on the author to stipulate what assumptions they're making - in my studies I had seen "ideal gas" as defined by $PV = nRT$, rather than $PV = nRT$ being a consequence of the assumptions made about its behaviour. In this case, one example of a model which I thought might be a non-ideal perfect gas is one in which interparticle interactions are disregarded, and the individual particles are yet still influenced by e.g. an external homogeneous gravitational field.